# How can I return user-values as a SPUser (Hyperlink) in a visual webpart in C#?

Tags: web-part, development, spuser

I'm developing a visual webpart (TreeView). If I click on a node (folder), it gives me the credentials of the folder. Now, the values are all appearing in a label.

How can I return the users and groups not as string, but as a "SPUser-Hyperlink" like you can see in lists, when you create a coloumn and select the field "persons and groups".

Answer (score 1):

```
String UserName= “UserNameGoesHere”; 

SPUser oUser= SPWeb.EnsureUser(UserName); 
treenode.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(oUser.Name);
```

Where “UserNameGoesHere” you can change that to a varible as you loop through each string.

or from msdn

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
using (SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs["Website_Name"])
{
    SPUser oUser = oWebsite.AllUsers["User_Name"];

    treenode.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(oUser.Name);

}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx

You would need to iterate through all the names by having in the using a while or forloop to go through the whole list!

hope this helps :)